# String.Split() - treating consecutive delimiters as one

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to parse a set of "fixed width" data files, I use that in quotes because the width is different per data file. However, the fields are separated by X number of spaces so I thought to just read in the line, and then do line.Split(' ')

However, this does not work for consecutive spaces!
!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have a couple options.

The first is to use the `string.Split()` overload that accepts a `StringSplitOptions` parameter and pass in `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] columns = lineOfText.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

That way, if you have multiple spaces in a row, the empty entries that are generated will be discarded.

The second option is to use a regular expression to do your parsing. This probably isn't necessary in your case, but could come in handy if the format becomes more complicated, or you expect it to change slightly over time.

Comment: +1, but Regex seems a bit overboard for splitting lines into space-separated values. Option 1 should be just fine.

Comment: @Stripling Fair enough; I feel it's preferable just because named capture groups and flexible contraints make adjusting to changing formats easier. But yeah, in this simple case option 1 is likely more than fine.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use a regex to achieve your desired result you would need to use [`Regex.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-5.0) instead:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string[] columns = new Regex(@"\s+", RegexOptions.Compiled).Split(lineOfText);
```